# Hide protocol in URL with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, https

I recently configured HTTPS on my Nginx server, however I think showing the protocol in the URL ( `http` / `https` ) is ugly. I was curious if there was a way for me to hide the protocol in the address bar, while still maintaining HTTPS security under the hood.

currently my URL looks like:
`https://example.com`
but I want it to look like `example.com`.

Any input much appreciated!

Comment: @Wesley what's wrong with asking? You can hide `http` from the URL, I've seen plenty of sites do it.

Comment: No you can't. That's entirely the browser.

Comment: @Prefix You haven't seen any sites do it. You've seen the browser do it.

Comment: "I think showing the protocol in the URL ( http / https ) is ugly." Not knowing if you're on HTTPS or not is dangerous. There's a reason browsers have chosen to do it this way. I'm also baffled at the idea that it's ugly somehow.

Comment: @ceejayoz most modern browsers indicate if the connection is secure or not with a little lock icon to the left of the address bar. The general hostility at simply asking a question here is what is truly baffling. Fuck me for not knowing something you knew, right? :)

Comment: @Prefix ServerFault's purpose is a bit on the "for professionals by professionals" side of the sliding scale, where there's a required base of understanding, experience, and searching / manual reading done before asking. If one went to a professional plumber's community and asked _"I see pipe. Has wrench now. WAT DO?"_ it would be met with some... shall we say... friction. Same here. You'll want a bit more experience and research skills to get the most out of ServerFault, that's all. SF is a tool, but has a few best practices for using it. Once you get the hang of it, it works a charm.

Comment: "for professionals by professionals" is pretty thinly veiled elitism. I'm here to learn, I apologize if I don't know what you know, but condescending comments (that have since been deleted) are not how you be nice as per: http://serverfault.com/help/be-nice

Comment: "For professionals by professionals" is no more elitism than entrance exams are for college. You have to have a certain base of knowledge to make the best use of a certain community. There are better communities for certain levels of skills than others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is entirely a function of the browser and has nothing to do with the HTTP server.